# Grouping based on Lag/Lead

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, partitioning, gaps-and-islands

In SQL Server 2014, I have the following table that tracks user activity:

| USER_ID | EVENT | EVENT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15552221111 | LOGIN | 2022-06-01 |
| 15552221111 | COMPLETE | 2022-06-08 |
| 15552221111 | LOGIN | 2022-09-01 |
| 15552221111 | SHUTDOWN | 2022-09-11 |
| 15552222222 | LOGIN | 2022-04-01 |
| 15552222222 | PROCESSING | 2022-04-08 |
| 15552222222 | PROCESSING | 2022-06-10 |
| 15552222222 | COMPLETE | 2022-06-11 |
| 15552222222 | LOGIN | 2022-09-08 |

I need to create some sort of sequencing value, so that all records that have an event less than 60 days of each other shares the same number. Desired result:

| USER_ID | EVENT | EVENT_DATE | SEQ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15552221111 | LOGIN | 2022-06-01 | 1 |
| 15552221111 | COMPLETE | 2022-06-08 | 1 |
| 15552221111 | LOGIN | 2022-09-01 | 2 |
| 15552221111 | SHUTDOWN | 2022-09-11 | 2 |
| 15552222222 | LOGIN | 2022-04-01 | 1 |
| 15552222222 | PROCESSING | 2022-04-08 | 1 |
| 15552222222 | PROCESSING | 2022-06-10 | 2 |
| 15552222222 | COMPLETE | 2022-06-11 | 2 |
| 15552222222 | LOGIN | 2022-09-08 | 3 |

Totally stuck, any ideas?

Here's some test code:

```
WITH testTable (USERID, EVENT, EVENT_DATE) AS
(
    SELECT 15552221111, 'LOGIN', '2022-06-01'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552221111, 'COMPLETE', '2022-06-01'   UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552221111, 'LOGIN', '2022-09-01'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552221111, 'SHUTDOWN', '2022-09-11'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552222222, 'LOGIN', '2022-04-01'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552222222, 'PROCESSING',  '2022-04-08 '  UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552222222, 'PROCESSING', '2022-06-10'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552222222, 'COMPLETE', '2022-06-11'    UNION ALL
    SELECT 15552222222, 'LOGIN', '2022-09-08'     
)     
SELECT 
    USERID
    , EVENT
    , EVENT_DATE
    , LEAD (EVENT_DATE, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) NEXT_DATE
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) RECORD_SEQ    
FROM testTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `LAG()` to determine the row when `EVENT_DATE` is more than 60 days when compare to previous row. And then perform a cumulative `SUM() OVER (..)` to get the `SEQ` that you want

```
CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    USERID
    , EVENT
    , EVENT_DATE
    , CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY
                       , LAG (EVENT_DATE, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE)
                       , EVENT_DATE) > 60
           THEN 1
           ELSE 0
          END AS S        
  FROM testTable 
)
SELECT *, SUM(S) OVER (PARTITION BY USERID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE) + 1 AS SEQ
FROM   CTE
```